# AWS CloudWatch events, reference a Lambda Function passing previously saved event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function which stops an RDS Database. To run this function it is only necessary call it using the **stop** saved event. [Stop Saved Eveent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbmO2.png)

When I input my [CloudWatch Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCbBi.png) rule, using the **Targets** -> **Configure input**, how could I generate an event to tell the lambda to execute my previously saved **stop** event.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That stop event is just a test event that you created, for testing Lambda functions in your web browser. That saved event isn't something you can reference later from things like CloudWatch Rules.

To modify the CloudWatch event being sent to your Lambda function to conform to the format you need, you would have to create a [CloudWatch Event Input Transformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html)